# I am Getting Strapi Email Api Error in Response : Internal Server Error

Tags: strapi

Getting "Internal Server Error" in response in Postman of Strapi Email API
"http://localhost:1337/email"

In VS Code Debug Console i am also getting this:

```
Error: Cannot wrap non-Error object
    application.js:190
          at Object.exports.assert (f:\app\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:740:11)
          at Object.exports.wrap (f:\app\node_modules\boom\lib\index.js:95:10)
          at strapi.app.use (f:\app\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\boom\index.js:40:20)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Also Gave Permission to access email api and i can also debug it in VS Code but the result is an error.

        POST Call to "http://localhost:1337/email" with Body:

      {
           "to":"asdf@yahoo.com",
           "from":"zxcv@yopmail.com",
           "replyTo": "zxcv@yopmail.com",
           "subject": "My message",
            "text": "Text"
        }
```

Result should be "OK" or "Email Sent"

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because you use the default email provider (sendmail).
And your computer is not an available smtp server.

So I suggest you to install `strapi-email-nodemailer` https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-email-nodemailer

Then in your admin panel, got to Plugins (menu link) > Email (cog icon) and the select nodemailer provider and set the smtp server you want to use.

If you have trouble to setup correct information I suggest you to check how `nodemailer` node module work. `strapi-email-provider` is just a connector to use `nodemailer` from Strapi.

Comment: but you also need to install strapi-provider-email-nodemailer

    npm i strapi-provider-email-nodemailer