# How to get Strapi email plugins to show up in the config dropdown

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to configure a Strapi v3.0.0-alpha.19 server to be able to send emails, specifically for resetting forgotten passwords. It's difficult to find sufficient documentation for this, but what I've read in answers to [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024692/i-am-getting-strapi-email-api-error-in-response-internal-server-error) is that I need to install the provider package, e.g. `strapi-provider-email-nodemailer`, and then set the SMTP server (an instruction with the transparency of a brick). However, when I install the package within project-folder/strapi and then reload http://localhost:1337/admin/plugins/email/configurations/development, the dropdown for providers still only contains the default provider, Sendmail.

I've tried rebuilding the Strapi API within my Docker container, but that doesn't make any difference.

I would expect Nodemailer to appear in the dropdown after refreshing the page, or at least after rebuilding the API, but that isn't happening. What steps do I need to take in order to designate Nodemailer as my email provider?

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the newer Strapi versions, you also have to manually change the email provider in the email plugin settings, as the dropdown with email providers is not available anymore (https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/6195). I just did it with amazon-ses after hours of research and it worked. Don't know if it's the right way to do it, but it's for sure the only way I managed to find after a very long time.

Go to `api/node_modules/strapi-plugin-email/config/settings.js` and change the provider to the desired one.

You should probably change yours like this:

```
module.exports = {
  provider: 'nodemailer',
  providerOptions: {},
  settings: {
    defaultFrom: 'Strapi <no-reply@strapi.io>',
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you've added both `strapi-email-nodemailer` and `strapi-provider-email-nodemailer`, next step should be adding configurations.

To add configuration, add below code in `plugin.js`. If you don't have `plugin.js`, then create one in root `config` folder.

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  email: {
    provider: "nodemailer",
    providerOptions: {
      nodemailer_default_from: "default_from_email@example.com",
      nodemailer_default_replyto: "default_replyto_email@example.com",
      host: "smtp.gmail.com, // Add your smtp host over here
      port: "995", // Add port number
      password: "<below-email-password>,
      username: "<email-address>",
      authMethod: "SMTP", // Auth method
    }
  },
});
```

You can save above configurations in your environment file and use it from there.

To send an email programmatically, add below code in your controller:

```
await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
  to: 'mail@example.com', // email recipient
  from: 'sender@example.com', // email sender
  subject: 'Email subject line', 
  text: 'Email body should come here'
});
```

Comment: I did the same thing using sendgrid provider , but still not working

Comment: how can i change to? i want to read it from the body

Answer (score 0):

Under `extensions/email` you can add a folder `config` and create the file `settings.js`, here you can configure this plugin

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  provider: 'nodemailer',
  providerOptions: {},
  settings: {
    defaultFrom: 'Name <name@email.com>',
  },
};
```